# Determine if page is valid in JavaScript - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, javascript, validation

What is the best way to determine if a form on an ASPX page is valid in JavaScript?

I am trying to check the validation of a user control that was opened using the JavaScript `window.showModalDialog()` and checking the 'Page.IsValid' property on the server side does not work.  I am using ASP.NET validation controls for page validation.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

If I have a page that is using a bunch of ASP.NET validation controls I will use code similar to the following to validate the page.  Make the call on an input submit.  Hopefully this code sample will get you started!

```
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick"ValidatePage();" />

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function ValidatePage() {

        if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            Page_ClientValidate();
        }

        if (Page_IsValid) {
            // do something
            alert('Page is valid!');                
        }
        else {
            // do something else
            alert('Page is not valid!');
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You answer plus reading the following post: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t292061-regarding-pageclientvalidate-function.html helped me solved my problem.

Comment: How could I modify the above code if I have multiple validation groups on the page and I just need to check if a single group is valid?

Comment: Update - I removed the `Page_ClientValidate()` call and it works :)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/3062770/292060 for arguments to this call, addressing the multiple validation groups.

Answer (score 9):

You are checking for `Page.IsValid` where you should be checking for `Page_IsValid` (it's a variable exposed by the .NET validators) :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was checking the Page.IsValid property on the server side on it was not working.

Answer (score 7):

The ASP.NET validation controls expose a client side API you can use with javascript: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx

You should be able to check the Page_IsValid object to see if any of the validation controls are invalid.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[id$=Button2]").click(function () {
    var validated = Page_ClientValidate('repo');
    if (validated) {
        // JavaScript code.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and the [Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) plugin to perform client side validation.  This will work with both html tags and asp.net server controls.  [Phil Haack has a good sample project](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/21/combining-jquery-form-validation-and-ajax-submission-with-asp.net.aspx) that will show you the basics.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203844/jquery-validation-plugin-disable-validation-for-specified-submit-buttons) has an in depth review of this approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

Set `ValidationGroup` property for each `asp.net` validator control in your page, you have to provide same name to `ValidationGroup` in a page.

For example:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required" ValidationGroup="Validate"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RangeValidator" ValidationGroup="Validate"></asp:RangeValidator>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" ValidationGroup="Validate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

After that in your javascript call like `Page_ClientValidate("ValidationGroup")`

For example:

```
function ValidatePage(){
if(Page_ClientValidate("Validate")){ //validate using above validation controls group
      //validation return true section
}
else{
      //validation return false section
}
}
```