# asp.net - manually run client-side validation code from another event

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I want to run whatever client-side validation routine is hooked up to a particular text input element.

The validation has been set up using `CustomValidator`:

```
<asp:textbox id="AddEstTime" runat="server" Width="55px"></asp:textbox><br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="AddEstTimeCustomValidator" ClientValidationFunction="AddEstTimeCustomValidator_ClientValidate" OnServerValidate="AddEstTimeCustomValidator_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="Please enter a time" ControlToValidate="AddEstTime"  runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ValidateEmptyText="true"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="AddIsTM" runat="server" Text="T&amp;M" />
```

and the javascript:

```js
function AddEstTimeCustomValidator_ClientValidate(sender, args) {
    var checkbox = $("input[id$='IsTM']");
    args.IsValid = checkbox.is(":checked") || args.Value.match(/^\d+$/);
}
```

When the `CheckBox` "AddIsTM" state changes, I want to revalidate the `textbox` "AddEstTime", using its hooked-up `CustomValidator` "AddEstTimeCustomValidator".

I am aware of focus -> add a character refocus -> remove character.  I am trying to find a more correct way.  New to asp.NET.

Comment: Why is important to check only one Validator ? You can run validation for whole page, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066857/determine-if-page-is-valid-in-javascript-asp-net

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It causes all the other validation errors to appear, so errors appear everywhere before the user has had a chance to get to those parts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking through the Microsoft client-side code, I came up with this which seems to work:

```
// client-side validation of one user-control.
// pass in jquery object with the validation control
function ValidateOneElement(passedValidator) {
    if (typeof (Page_Validators) == "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    $.each(Page_Validators, function (index, value) {
        if ($(value).attr("id") == passedValidator.attr("id")) {
            ValidatorValidate(value, null, null);
        }
    });
}
```

This was after examining the `Page_ClientValidate` function:

```
function Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup) {
    Page_InvalidControlToBeFocused = null;
    if (typeof(Page_Validators) == "undefined") {
        return true;
    }
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i], validationGroup, null);
    }
    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
    ValidationSummaryOnSubmit(validationGroup);
    Page_BlockSubmit = !Page_IsValid;
    return Page_IsValid;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

thx sennett (voted)

i just ran the simplest JS

```
Page_ClientValidate();
```

if you have a validation group then is

```
Page_ClientValidate("validationGroupName")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want stick with ASP.NET validators eventually you can [abuse Validation Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560812/page-clientvalidate-with-multiple-validationgroups-how-to-show-multiple-summ), but I think that this approach will give you nothing but trouble. Other option is to use jQuery on the client (nice [list](http://www.antsmagazine.com/web-development/excellent-jquery-plugins-to-enhance-form-validation/)) only then you will have to duplicate validation on the server side, or to avoid that call server methods from client validations.

Comment: That was exactly what I ended up doing.  I guess the answer is "no, there isn't a simple way of running a validator for one control".