# Page_ClientValidate returns false but none of the validators have errors

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using Page_ClientValidate for validations.

It returns false even there is no invalid inputs.

```
  function PageValid() {

            var valid = Page_ClientValidate('save');

            alert(valid);

            if (valid == true) {

                $('.mydiv').hide();
            }

        }
```

Here 'save' is the validation group. Please help me guys.

Thanks,
Rajbir

Comment: provide markup of your validators and button on which you are call this method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go through [ASP.NET Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx) and [Java script page validation Page_clientValidate()](http://weblogs.asp.net/pirabdulwakeel/archive/2010/09/02/java-script-page-validation-page-clientvalidate.aspx)

> The Job of this function is to check the page is it valid if any of
>   the validator is not valid this function return false otherwise it
>   return true.

```
if (Page_ClientValidate()) {

// Page is Ok

//Submit it To The Server

return true
} else {

//Page is Not Valid

//Return False

return false

}
```

It may possible that you are missing about validation settings on your validator or some other error on js.

You can do manual validation as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    /* Manual client-side validation of Validator Groups */
    function fnJSOnFormSubmit() {
        var isGrpOneValid = Page_ClientValidate("valGrpOne");
        var isGrpTwoValid = Page_ClientValidate("valGrpTwo");

        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++) { 
            ValidatorValidate(Page_Validators[i]); //this forces validation in all groups
        }

        //display all summaries.
        for (i = 0; i < Page_ValidationSummaries.length; i++) {
            summary = Page_ValidationSummaries[i];
            //does this summary need to be displayed?
            if (fnJSDisplaySummary(summary.validationGroup)) {
                summary.style.display = ""; //"none"; "inline";
            }
        }

        if (isGrpOneValid && isGrpTwoValid)
            return true; //postback only when BOTH validations pass.
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Ref:
[Page_ClientValidate() with multiple ValidationGroups - how to show multiple summaries simultaneously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560812/page-clientvalidate-with-multiple-validationgroups-how-to-show-multiple-summ)
[Page_ClientValidate is validating multiple times.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/969465/problem-with-page-clientvalidate)

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this for a bit